# ColorBox iframe - requested url /undefined not found on the server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

I've been trying to add the latest [ColorBox](https://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) jquery plugin to a site I'm building, and every time I try to load a url in an ifrae popup I get the following message displayed within the iframe (the frame itself generates perfectly - it just cannot sem to pull in the content):

```
>Not Found
>
>The requested URL /myfolder/undefined was not found on this server.
```

I have tried this with links found locally (e.g. info_page.php) and external links (e.g. http://www.google.com). I cannot figure out why it isn't loading, as my code is lifted almost directly from the colorBox examples.

My html (in the head) is:

```
    <!--COLORBOX-->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%",     height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, 'href' : $(this).attr('href'), width:"80%", height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
            });
            
            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    <!--END COLORBOX-->
```

And the body link I use to generate this is:

```
    <a class="iframe" href="http://google.com/">Test</a>
```

The javascript files and css files I have not changed from the ones found on the colorBox site.Any help would be appreciated - if more info is needed let me know.

(NB: I am currently running the site locally)
 [http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/](https://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?

ColorBox uses ajax to load content dynamically and many browsers prevent that action as an implementation of security policy.  Developing locally can sometimes unintentionally result in the prohibited case.

Things to consider:

Do you see this behavior in all browsers?
Can you install the project on a true remote server?

PS. Sorry this isn't exactly an "answer" in the true SO sense...

Comment: Hi Kevin M, thanks for answering.

I am using the latest Chrome and have tested on Firefox - same issue on both. I don't have a web host to upload to right now, but other Ajax calls made locally seem to work. 

It's very odd - I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Hey Josh,  Your code works perfectly for me on Chrome 16.0.912.blah blah and FFox 7.0.1 in the following cases: (a) href pointing to local file, (b) href pointing to external link using full format ("=== http : // www.bing.com ===").  Could it be as simple as that?  Note that I used ONLY the statement $(".iframe").colorbox... in my test, so maybe something is conflicting elsewhere in the demo code. (If you don't need it, comment it out...)

Comment: Sorry mess in the URL cited above for Bing; I couldn't defeat SO's auto formatting of it. The point is to change your URL reference to a more fully qualified format.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I'd love to say what did or didn't work in the end, but basically I just ended up re-installing the whole code from scratch (as in, getting rid of all colorbox references and then re-adding them) and it then worked. Apologies if anyone has the same problem - I couldn't pinpoint the exact cause, but that solved it for me.